# Unable to display two div elements next to each other using CSS grid

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, css-grid

I am trying to get the div element with the "sidebar" class and the div element with the "editorWindow" class in a column next to each other, but it doesn't work.

```
    <div className="mainWrap">
      <div className="sidebar">
         <div className="innerSidebar">
          <div className="sidebarLogo">
            <img src="/code-socket-light.png" className="sidebarLogo" alt="Sidebar Logo"/>
          </div>
          <h3>Connected Users</h3>
          <div className="userList">
            {
              users.map(eachUser => <User key={eachUser.socketId} username={eachUser.username}/>)
            }
          </div>
         </div>
         <button className="btn copyBtn">Copy Code Room ID</button>
         <button className="btn leaveBtn">Leave Code Room</button>
      </div>
      <div className="editorWindow">
        <Editor />
      </div>
    </div>
```

This is the CSS that I used

```
.mainWrap{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 230px 1fr;
}
.sidebar{
  background: #1c1e29;
  padding: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

What is going wrong?

I was trying to display the two divs inside the 'mainWrap' div next to each other using CSS grid, but for some reason it isn't working.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Its work

```css
.mainWrap {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 230px 1fr;
}
.sidebar {
  background: #1c1e29;
  padding: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
    <div class="mainWrap">
      <div class="sidebar">
        <div class="innerSidebar">
          <div class="sidebarLogo">
            <img
              src="/code-socket-light.png"
              class="sidebarLogo"
              alt="Sidebar Logo"
            />
          </div>
          <h3>Connected Users</h3>
          <div class="userList">User</div>
        </div>
        <button class="btn copyBtn">Copy Code Room ID</button>
        <button class="btn leaveBtn">Leave Code Room</button>
      </div>
      <div class="editorWindow">edittor</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Yes it works. Actually it was just an issue with the comments syntax. I mistakenly used double slashes to enter some comments in the CSS file which disabled the CSS written write beneath the comments, and for some reason the color coding did not change, indicating that the CSS is disabled. Thanks for the answer though .